# Attribute names with underscores in DS.Error

Tags: validation, ember.js, ember-data

Is it possible for attributes within DS.Errors to keep the underscores. I have a field name as value=first_name. This is the response I get back from the server:

```
errors: {
  first_name: ["enter name"]
}
```

When I console.log the response from a promise, the attribute is camelCased (firstName). I'm aware this is the default behaviour from Ember, but I was wondering if it is possible to keep the attribute name as first_name for the errors?

I've seen:

```
App.ApplicationSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
  keyForAttribute: function(attr) {
    return Ember.String.underscore(attr).toUpperCase();
  }
});
```

But this hasn't done anything to the response and I cannot find an example to keep underscores for errors.

I've added a jsbin to help show my issue: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/jicuvu/1/edit

Comment: In your jsbin, you've added `Ember.String.camelize(key)`. Did you mean to do this? That's the only thing making `first_name` camelCase.

Comment: rogMaHall - it was right in front of me and I couldn't see it. Doh! If you want to add that as an answer then I will select it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: No worries, just need someone else to read through your sometimes. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, Ember shouldn't be affecting the errors object attributes, you just added the camelCasing yourself (it seems by accident). The forEach should just be as follows:

```
 Ember.keys(jsonErrors).forEach(function(key) {
   return errors[key] = jsonErrors[key];
 });
```

If you were, however, trying to get rid of Ember's default camelCased serializing on models, you could use pathForType in the RESTAdapter:

```
var Adapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  ...
  pathForType: function(type) {
    return Ember.String.underscore(type);
  }
  ...
});
```